# Run a js file with Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

How do I make a Chrome Extension run a js file from a web location?
And make it automatically run on a domain.

I don't know much about Chrome Extensions.

For example I want to run https://example.com/example.js automatically on the domain https://example.com using a chrome extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Declare a [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) in manifest.json:

  ```js
  {
      "name": "Execute js",
      "version": "1.0",
      "manifest_version": 2,
      "content_scripts": [{
          "matches": ["https://example.com/*"],
          "js": ["content.js"]
      }]
  }
  ```
- The content script `content.js` will insert an element that loads the js script:

  ```js
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.src = '/example.js';
  document.head.appendChild(script);
  ```

Comment: Thanks you that's just what I needed. :)

Comment: any idea how to run js inside a tab opened by chrome extension?